# Android Java : How to propertly close ObjectInputStream and FileInputStream

Tags: java, android, fileinputstream, objectinputstream

Below I try to close the streams but in StrictMode, I keep getting :

**"A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks".**

The line being refered to being :

`FileInputStream   FIS  = new FileInputStream(file);`

Here's the code :

```
public static <T> T getStoredList(File file) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
      FileInputStream   FIS  = new FileInputStream(file);
      ObjectInputStream OIS  = new ObjectInputStream(FIS);
      List<T>           data = (ArrayList) OIS.readObject();
      FIS.close();
      OIS.close();
      return (T) data;
   }
```

After the comment below I updated the code to :

```
public static <T> T getStoredList(File file) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
      FileInputStream   FIS = null;
      ObjectInputStream OIS = null;
      try {
         FIS = new FileInputStream(file);
         OIS = new ObjectInputStream(FIS);
         List<T> data = (ArrayList) OIS.readObject();
         return (T) data;
      } finally {
         if (FIS != null) {
            FIS.close();
         }
         if (OIS != null) {
            OIS.close();
         }
      }
   }
```

But with this, (T) data is null.

Comment: use a `try...finally` block

Comment: @ScaryWombat please see my edit. After using the try...finally, I get null results.

Comment: I can not see anything that you have changed that would suddenly result in null data - check your file.

Comment: @ScaryWombat you're right. There was something wrong with the file.